# mega dropdown navigation menu not covering div with position relative

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, position

i found [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) mega dropdown menu using CSS3. this worked perfectly but i have any problem. i put `DIV` with `position:relative` after this menu. now, when i `hover` `LI` menu (home), dropdown not covering my div. how to fix this ? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/b6r9Q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the z-index of your dropdown columns.  See here http://jsfiddle.net/b6r9Q/3/

```
.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    z-index:500;
    margin:4px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;

    /* Gradient background */
    background:#F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/b6r9Q/1/

Just put z-index: 1; in the dropdown columns.